# only need to delete one product from my cart, not all products with same ID

Tags: php, foreach, shopping-cart

I don't understand why this code won't only delete the pizza_id with the given key that is passed through the URL. I echo back the `$_GET['key']` value to check if I have the desired number and it works fine. 
The key value comes from another `foreach $key=>$value` loop that builds the shopping cart and has a delete link with the pizza id and the $key in it.

```
switch ($action) {
    case 'add':
        if ($cart) {
            $cart .= ','.$_GET['pizza_id'];
        } else {
            $cart = $_GET['pizza_id'];
        }
        break;
    case 'delete':
        echo "KEY: ".$_GET['key']."<br>";
        if ($cart) {
            $items = explode(',',$cart);
            $newcart = '';
            foreach ($items as $key => $item) 
            {
                if ($_GET['pizza_id'] != $item && $GET['key']!= $key ) 
                {
                    if ($newcart != '') 
                    {
                        $newcart .= ','.$item;
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        $newcart = $item;
                    }
                }
            }
            $cart = $newcart;
        }
        break;
}
```

EDIT: maybe I should also mention the basis of the code comes from this webpage http://v3.thewatchmakerproject.com/journal/276/

Comment: delete? You have no "delete" code here

Comment: I added code to make it more complete. When you click the link that says "delete" on another page, there is a GET variable that has the value "delete" and it gets passed in the url.

Comment: I can't understand why you perform a double check on pizza_id and key parameters. Anyway, the second one has $GET['key'] instead of $_GET['key'].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, at a minimum, you don't need the $key in the foreach.

```
if ($cart) {
    // you car is now an array of $items.
    $items = explode(',',$cart);
    $key = $_GET[ 'key' ];
    // are you sure pizza_id is correct too? You may want to echo/log it
    // if there is an $item which corresponds to $key, remove it.
    if( isset( $items[ $key ] ) )
          unset( $items[ $key ] );

    // this loop searches for all indexes of $_GET[ 'pizza_id' ] and removes them
    // comment this out if you don't want to do that. For some reason 
    // I missed it the first go round.
    while( ($pos = $array_search( $items, $_GET[ 'pizza_id' ] ) !== FALSE )
    {
        array_splice( $items, $pos, 1 );
    }
    // implode afterwards
    $cart = implode( ',', $items );
}
```

Another poster pointed out that your original code also has `$GET['key']`. Badness 10000. Do you have your warnings and error output set at the maximum level during development?

Comment: Hi, Yes pizza_id is correct too since the part of the desired result is deleting jus that pizza_id. And as a matter of fact, my code does work for that pizza_id. Problem is, if my cart has multiple pizza's with the same id, it deletes all pizzas with the same id, instead of just the one you clicked.

Comment: How does the code above take into account that a 'delete' - link is being clicked and sends you to the page with this code? As for the typo: I use Netbeans 7.0 as I find it to be quite strict on my coding errors. Don't really understand why Netbeans is tolerant to this.

Comment: This code replaces what is between the `case 'delete':` and the `break`.

Comment: As to Netbeans -- Netbeans is pretty good with PHP (some might say the best), but while debugging, you should still have your server set to the maximum error output level.

Comment: thanks very much for the input. Getting some minor errors now as I need to fit in the rest of code probable going to check it further real soon. Thanks also for the news about the server

Answer (score 0):

Check if this will work

```
foreach ($items as $key => $item) 
                            {
                if ($_GET['pizza_id'] != $item && $GET['key']!= $item )
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't get your problem ... but you have a typo in the if-condition.

```
$GET[
```

lacks the underscore ...